# JavaScript twitter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I currently have a calculator, which generates output.  I'm currently trying to generate a dynamic twitter button along with the output.  I've made several attempts to get the twitter button to work, but it either shows up as a text link or doesn't show up at all.  The code below is what I've used.

**Method 1**

```
  $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
  var twit_link = $('<a/>', {
    href : 'https://www.twitter.com/share',
    'class' : 'twitter-share-button',
    url : 'http://www.twitter.com/obamamakes',
    'data-count' : 'none',
    'data-via' : 'ObamaMakes',
    'data-text' : 'In the time it takes me to ' + activity + ', Barack Obama makes $' + i.toFixed(1)
  }).text('Tweet');
 $("#CalcOutput").html( twit_link );
```

**Method 2**

```
$("#CalcOutput-twitter").html("<a href=\"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=\"" + encodeURIComponent(result) + "\" class=\"twitter-share-button-activity\" url=\"http://www.twitter.com/obamamakes\" data-count=\"none\" data-via=\"ObamaMakes\" data-text=\"In the time it takes me to " + activity + ", Barack Obama makes $" + i.toFixed(1) + "> <img src=\"IMAGES/twitter.jpg\" id=\"imgTweet\" alt=\"Tweet This\" width=\"50px\" height=\"30px\"></a>");
```

**Method 3**

```
$("#CalcOutput-twitter").html("<a href=\"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=\"" + encodeURIComponent(result) + "\" ><img src=\"IMAGES/twitter.jpg\" id=\"imgTweet\" alt=\"Tweet This\" width=\"50px\" height=\"30px\"></a>");
```

Comment: [First code looks fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/PjaS6/). Did you remember to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function() {...})` ?

Comment: It may look fine, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it works for me -- the problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to load the twitter script after the link is present on the page. so make sure this code that you wrote runs first, others wise twitters script won't pick it up.

Meaning : use any of your methods first then you run this code

```
$.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
```

**Example**:

```
var twit_link = $('<a/>', {
    href : 'https://www.twitter.com/share',
    'class' : 'twitter-share-button',
    url : 'http://www.twitter.com/obamamakes',
    'data-count' : 'none',
    'data-via' : 'ObamaMakes',
    'data-text' : 'In the time it takes me to ' + activity + ', Barack Obama makes $' + i.toFixed(1)
}).text('Tweet');
$("#CalcOutput").html( twit_link );
$.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
```

Comment: I'm sort of confused by what you mean.  Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Since `$.getScript` is asynchronous, it won't finish loading until after the next two lines of code are executed anyway.

Comment: I took Ibu's advice, but I don't think it changed anything.

Comment: well does the element with id `CalcOutput` exist on your page? did you spell it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the script after the widgets.js file is pulled, then you might want to hook on the success callback.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ for more information

```
$.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js", function(script, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var activity, i;
    activity = 0;
    i = 4.56;
    var twit_link = $('<a/>', {
        href: 'https://www.twitter.com/share',
        'class': 'twitter-share-button',
        url: 'http://www.twitter.com/obamamakes',
        'data-count': 'none',
        'data-via': 'ObamaMakes',
        'data-text': 'In the time it takes me to ' + activity + ', Barack Obama makes $' + i.toFixed(1)
    }).text('Tweet');
    $("#CalcOutput").html(twit_link);
});​
```